# How to add List of EntityField to List of SyncEntity?

Tags: c#

I want to store List of EntityField into List of SyncEntity, but i get error, Below is my code snippet:

```
 List<SyncEntity>  syncEntities = new List<SyncEntity>
        {
            new SyncEntity {Name ="Doors_Module2",Id = "1",
                   new EntityField{Name = "Field1"},
                    new EntityField{Name="Field2"}},
            new SyncEntity {Name ="Doors_Module2",Id = "2"},
            new SyncEntity {Name ="Doors_Module2",Id = "3"},
            new SyncEntity {Name ="Doors_Module2",Id = "4"}
        };
```

I get error while storing list. Please Help me

Comment: how do you try to store it?

Comment: does EntityField inherit SyncEntity?

Comment: I want to send syncEntities as a parameter to another function

Comment: SyncEntity have list of EntityField

Comment: Is there any solution for this

Comment: Give `SyncEntity` class

Comment: public class SyncEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Id { get; set; }

       
        public List<EntityField> EntityFields { get; set; }

    }
    public class EntityField
    {
        
        public string Name { get; set; }
       
        public string Type { get; set; }
      
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 1):

Solution is simple. This is how your `class` is defined,

```
public class SyncEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<EntityField> EntityFields { get; set; }
}
```

If you see the `EntityFields` property, it expects a list of `EntityField` to be assigned to it.
Now if you observe your code, the first `SyncEntity` object you are creating is something like this,

```
new SyncEntity
{
    Name = "Doors_Module2",
    Id = "1",
    new EntityField { Name = "Field1" }, //adding object instead of list
    new EntityField { Name = "Field2" }  //adding object instead of list
}
```

As in the comments you are adding two individual objects instead of a list.
So you have to add those two objects as a list. Like,

```
new SyncEntity
{
    Name = "Doors_Module2",
    Id = "1",
    EntityFields = new List<EntityField> {
        new EntityField { Name = "Field1" },
        new EntityField { Name = "Field2" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnak you so much , its really work like what i want...once again thanks

Comment: welcome... Mark it as answer if it gives what you need.